# Maximum sum of sub list in a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Making my first steps in Python.
I have a list of lists and i'm trying to return the **sub list** with largest sum of all sub lists.
For now I just have the max sum itself.
Ex: this code returns 18, but I need to return [3,3,3,3,3,3]

Any directions?
Thanks

```
def find_biggest(lst):
    inner_list_sum = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        inner_list_sum.append(sum(lst[i]))    # list of elements sums
    return max(inner_list_sum)                # I actually need the element itself...not the max sum

print(find_biggest([[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,3], [1,1], [3,3,3,3,3,3]]))
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `max` with `key=sum`

**Ex:**

```
data = [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,3], [1,1], [3,3,3,3,3,3]]
print(max(data, key=sum))
```

**Output:**

```
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Key explanation: the `key` parameter to `max` tells it how to find the value that it's maximizing (as opposed to using the value of the element directly), in this case by applying the `sum` function.

Comment: wow this is sooooo good, i would never have though to do this

Comment: I tried this one but it returns None apart  from the correct answer . Ex: when enter this code as an answer I get back a mistake:                                      
 Input Expected Got 
test = [[1, 2, 3], [10, -2],  [1, 1, 1, 1]]
print(find_biggest(test))
test = [[1, 2, 3], [10, -2],  [1, 1, 1, 1]]
print(find_biggest(test))
[10, -2]
[10, -2]
None

Answer (score 0):

OK
Since I'm not allowed to use (max(data, key=sum)).
I did this not very elegant code, but it was accepted a correct answer

```
def find_biggest(lst):
    inner_list_sum = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        inner_list_sum.append(sum(lst[i]))    # list of elements sums
        max_element=max(inner_list_sum)
        seq_index= inner_lis
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import functools

def find_biggest(lst):
    return functools.reduce(lambda x, y : x if sum(x) > sum(y) else y, lst)
```

Here, the used `lambda` expression is the function equivalent to find the greatest sum and `lst` is `iterable`.

Please note: `reduce` will directly work for `python2`, you need to import `functools`
for `python3`only.

[Using functools.reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)

Comment: ```print(find_biggest([[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,3], [1,1], [3,3,3,3,3,3]])) returns [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]```